# Idiomatic preposition after 'insult'

Tags: prepositions

We use "criticism of", "comments on/about", but what preposition should follow the noun 'insult'? I've searched through multiple dictionary entries but had no luck finding any relevant examples. Here is my context:

- Thomas' insults ... the minority group provoked considerable controversy.

Even though I found a lot of example sentences using the preposition 'to', my impression is that the 'to' after 'insult' serves to limit the word's effect to a certain individual/group. Like if I say 'It's an insult to me', I am basically stating that I feel disrespected by something said or done, but that thing isn't NECESSARILY consciously directed at me (which is what I wanted to express). Is this line of thought correct?

Comment: "of" or "to" (the latter with an implied verb "delivered")

Comment: I think something meaning *about* is better. I would use *regarding*.

Comment: @user3169, it's interesting that 'insults' doesn't seem to have a preposition that we would strongly associate it with. Perhaps the construction I have provided isn't in common use?

Comment: You should add this information to your question, along with some of the "to" examples you found.

Answer (score 2):

Since "insults" is clearly negative, I'd use **against**.

Another alternative would be **toward(s)**.

The latter would be more in line with "to", which is defined as the usual preposition in the Oxford Collocations Dictionary:

[image: Insult to]

"to" sounds to me to be better when "insult" is in the singular. The reason might be that the specificity of "(one) insult" also requires a specific addressee for whom such an insult is intended, and this directness is better conveyed by "to".